# How to align joomla plugin through code

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions, joomla1.6, joomla-template

I am developing joomla 1.5 and 1.6 plugin(s).

I am providing two input parameters:

1. Alignment ( Left or right )
2. Display plugin ( after article or before article)

Through code; is there any way to align plugin left or right, also display plugin before or after article.

Please suggest your pointers for joomla 1.5 and joomla 1.6 version !

Thanks
Pravin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this can be succeed by overwriting the com_content templates.

Maybe you can put a special text pattern like {PLUGIN_LEFT} and {PLUGIN_RIGHT} to the custom component template in /templates/TEMPLATE_NAME/html/com_content/article/default.php.You need to locate these patterns left and right side of the content.

In the content plugin, you can replace these patterns with your plugin output.